# How to inject an indirect ancestor component in Angular2

Tags: angular, parent, inject, ancestor

In Angular2 it's possible to inject an parent or even ancestor (eg. grandparent) component to child by simply using the following syntax:

```ts
export class Grandchild {
   constructor( @Optional() @Host() @Inject(forwardRef(() => Ancestor)) ancestor)
}
```

However, that seems to work only for ancestor-grandchild relations that are defined in a single template, like following:

```ts
<!-- App component template -->
<ancestor>
  <foobar>
    <grandchild></grandchild>  <!-- injection works -->
  </foobar>
</ancestor>
```

If, instead our templates would be like as follows, the injection will not work:

```ts
<!-- App component template -->
<ancestor>
  <foobar></foobar>
</ancestor>

<!-- Foobar component template -->
<grandchild></grandchild>  <!-- injection doesn't work -->
```

I have made a plunker for this: http://plnkr.co/edit/D9iSokONIAFAS8G1NTd1

Comment: I don't think that is supported.

Comment: I hope that's not the case, but if so, then I think I should file a bug report to Angular2.

Comment: As far as I know only the direct parent can be injected. You can provide a service at the grandparent that can be injected by any descendant. I'm pretty sure a bug report is redundant.

Comment: That idea for using a service provided by grandparent could be the key. Though there is a problem with the "Optional" part then, though that's possible to overcome with another hack. Probably you should modify your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a shared service and use it to communicate.

```ts
@Injectable()
class SharedService {
  grandParent = new BehaviorSubject();
}

@Component({
  selector: 'grand-parent',
  providers: [SharedService],
  ...
})
class GrandParent {
  constructor(sharedService:SharedService) {
    sharedService.grandParent.next(this);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'descendant',
  providers: [],
  ...
})
class Descendant {
  constructor(@Optional() sharedService:SharedService) {
    if(sharedService) {
      sharedService.grandParent.subscribe(grandParent => this.grandParent = grandParent);
    }
  }
}
```

In practice I wouldn't send a reference to `this` but use observables to send messages the receiver acts on.

Comment: Good answer. The missing "@Optional" functionality can be achieved by using a dummy application level provider for that "SharedService", only difference being that the reference to "Grandparent" is undefined. My special use case is to create custom inline-edit fields that may act independently (inline edit) or as a part of a custom form (traditional edit). I think I will use direct reference from input (child) to optional form (ancestor) components instead of observables in this particular case, though observables are typically the recommended solution.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the "missing @Optional functionality". That can be used with services as well.

Comment: I did mean that you need to always have a provider for service. And if you happen to use a "child" without "ancestor" (thus ancestor being optional), you need to provide that shared service on application level, to prevent Angular2 crashing. If you think about an HTML equivalent for this, it's that you can use <input> elements without a <form> element, but if you happen to have <input> elements within a <form>, their values will be sent when <form> is submitted. Therefore <form> is an optional ancestor for <input>, providing additional functionality.

Comment: But that's exactly what the `@Optional()` decorator does. If DI can't find a provider, it passes `null` instead of crashing.

Comment: Oh well, my bad. Didn't notice that @Optional() before, and hadn't ever used them for a service...

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/WgUbgApd0UWXrjAwxco4?p=preview  <- working plunker example with shared service.